# Create a nested data.frame from separate lists

Tags: r, tidyr, tidyverse

I'd like to create a nested data.frame similar to nesting in the `tidyr` package. but I do not yet have my data in a `data.frame` so I cannot simply `df %>% group_by(thing) %>% nest()` I have 3 lists that correspond to the three columns I'm trying to bring together. See the example below:

```
library(tidyverse)

student = c('bob', 'jane', 'sam')
avg_score = c(95, 99, 80)
details = lapply(1:3, 
           function(x) data.frame(answer = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE),10, TRUE), 
                                  question_num = 1:10))
```

Now this is what I would like to do:

```
my_data_frame = data.frame(student = student, 
                           avg_score = avg_score, 
                           details = details)
```

But of course this wont work as `details` is not a list of atomics, but rather a list of `data.frame`s. I've also tried:

```
my_data_frame = data.frame(student = student, 
                           avg_score = avg_score, 
                           details = nest(details))
```

Comment: You can store a `list` column in `data.frame` using `I` i.e `details = I(details))`

Answer (score 3):

For those of you who run into a similar problem. the key is to use a `tibble` instead of a `data.frame`

```
library(tidyverse)

student = c('bob', 'jane', 'sam')
avg_score = c(95, 99, 80)
details = lapply(1:3, function(x) data.frame(answer = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 10, TRUE), question_num = 1:10))

my_nested_data_frame = tibble(student = student, avg_score = avg_score, details = details)
```